# How to get Json into a JS variable out of a Scala Json string?

Tags: javascript, json, scala, playframework

I'm using Play framework and trying to send a Json string from the server as a parameter to a Scala template.

```
@(aj: String)
@import play.api.libs.json.Json
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   <body>
      <div id="container">
        @aj
      </div>

    <script>
       var ab=@Json.toJson(aj);
       var a = JSON.parse(ab);
    </script>
    </body>
 </html>
```

I get the Json String displayed inside the container div. 
But I'm not able to get the Json out of 'aj' into a javascript variable.
Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In view you can do:

```
<script>
var json = @Html(aj),
obj = JSON.parse(json);
</script>
```

Comment: This works! Thanks. But not if if aj is a List or any other format. Something else required there?

Comment: `@Html` is displaying value as raw one. If other that `String` you will have to use formatting compatible with JS (e.g. date formatting, number formatter, ...). For `List` you can try something like: `var list = @Html(scalaList.mkString("[",",","]")); // format as [a,b,c,...,z]`.